# How to say to "persuade into doing something"?

Tags: phrase-requests

I am looking for a Japanese phrase or an idiom which could be used to describe a situation in which a person A persuades person B into doing something, not required for the person B, but beneficial to the A.

Like selling a trekking map for a very well marked and safe path.

I tried looking for "to scare someone to do something" and got literal 脅かして～させる, which I feel is too strong (there is no direct threat). だまして suggests deception (while A might only exaggerate certain aspects, not necessarily lie). On the other hand 説得する does not have a negative connotation.

Is there such a phrase? Or are my concerns for the above-mentioned phrases irrelevant?

Comment: Kind of  vague, but are you suggesting something *different* from "an offer you can't refuse"?

Comment: "I bought this map because the guy made an offer I could not refuse"? No, I guess that's not what I'm looking for.

Comment: Well I wasn't sure if it was implied with that map comment that it was not a direct threat but an indirect one suggesting that the person would likely die (possibly by some nefarious means) if they didn't use the map this seller was kind enough to offer.

Comment: I'm looking for "to put someone in reality-distortion field" :-)

Comment: @ssb "Buy this map, everyone does it and they are very satisfied" is not a threat, but is a possibility in a situation I am looking to describe.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would suggest **[言いくるめる](http://jisho.org/search/%E8%A8%80%E3%81%84%E3%81%8F%E3%82%8B%E3%82%81%E3%82%8B)**, which is like 説得する/説き伏せる, but implies the action is beneficial not to the target but to the subject. It does have the negative connotation like 騙す, but it's not as strong/evil/illegal as 騙す.

You can also use [丸め込む](http://eow.alc.co.jp/search?q=%E4%B8%B8%E3%82%81%E8%BE%BC%E3%82%80) and [口車【くちぐるま】に乗せる](http://eow.alc.co.jp/search?q=%E5%8F%A3%E8%BB%8A&ref=sa).

> - 彼をうまく言いくるめて、地図を買わせよう。
> - 店員に言いくるめられて、3万円もする服を買わされてしまった。別に欲しくなかったのに。
> - 彼の口車には乗るな。 Don't be cajoled by him.

Answer (score 7):

An expression that comes to mind would be:

> 「[説]{と}き[伏]{ふ}せる」

That is stronger than 「[説得]{せっとく}する」, but it never involves threat of any kind.　All it involves is the art of conversation - [話術]{わじゅつ}.

Together with another verb, you can use it like:

> 「～～するよう（に）説き伏せる」 or
>
> 「説き伏せて～～させる」

「Aは、その地図を買うよう（に）Bを説き伏せた。」

「Aは、Bを説き伏せてその地図を買わせた。」

Answer (score 0):

### 強{し}いる or 押{お}し付{つ}ける perhaps?

> 地図を強いられた
>
> 地図を押し付けられた